# How to automatically log out the guest session user after idle time

Tags: linux-mint, logout, guest-account

On a PC for public use people enter very private data, then don't logout, which doesn't seem optimal, so I would like if anyone could tell me how to automatically log out the guest session user after idle time. The OS is Linux Mint 18.3 64-bit Cinnamon. All the ways of automatically logging somebody out I have found, don't seem to work for the guest session.

Answer (score 0):

Use [autolog](https://packages.debian.org/buster/autolog)

### "Log out idle users

The program reads the utmp file, entry by entry. The username for each 'user process' is compared to the entries in the configuration file. The first entry to match both the name, the group, and the tty line of the process will be used to conduct the automatic logout."

Comment: Will this work even if my distro is not LMDE?

Comment: Additionally, found out that this doesn't seem to work either, in that I have to either specify the user, which I can't since guest-session has random username each time, or I have to add the guest session to a group through /etc/guest-session/prefs.sh, but this somehow makes me unable to login with it